# Linq group by select

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ expression and I need to add two extrastring fields (newFieldWhat and newFieldBy) to Record-object in the result-list. The String-value could be either first or last, no difference. How can i achieve that?

```
List<Record> groupedTable = (from t in recordTable
                    group t by new {t.groupBy1}
                    into grp
                        select new
                        Record{
                            groupBy1 = grp.Key.groupBy1,
                            attribute1 = grp.Sum(t => t.attribute1),
                            newFieldWhat = ?
                            newFieldBy = ?
                        }).OrderBy(a => a.groupBy1).ToList();
```

Comment: `grp.First()`,`grp.Last()` or do you mean something else?

Comment: Are you asking how you can add properties to the Record class?...

Comment: You cannot modify your class `Record` on the fly. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: newFieldWhat = grp.First(t => t.newFieldWhat) gives me cannot convert 'string' to 'bool'. newFieldWhat is a string

Comment: what i'm trying to achieve is to group list by one (or two) columns and sum  one column(attribute1) values while keeping first(last) values of newFieldWhat, newFieldBy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comment makes it clearer:

> ```
> newFieldWhat = grp.First(t => t.newFieldWhat)
> ```
>
> gives me: "cannot convert 'string' to 'bool'. newFieldWhat is a
>   string"

I think you want:

```
newFieldWhat = grp.First().newFieldWhat
```

or, if you want all of the group:

```
newFieldWhat = String.Join(",", grp.Select(t => t.newFieldWhat))
```

Comment: newFieldWhat = grp.First().newFieldWhat was what i needed. thank you

Comment: @user2542809: if you expect only dulicates the first is efficient and correct. But maybe you want to use the second anyway. It has the advantage that it shows all of the group comma separated. You could use `grp.Select(t => t.newFieldWhat).Distinct()` if you only want to see if there are different. If there are none the result is the same as with `First().newFieldWhat` since the comma is not appended.